# How to query data that does not contain any given keywords in the json

Tags: mysql, database

Question:How to query data that does not contain any given keywords in the flag.

The form looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `mangas` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `flag` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And then the table has data that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO `mangas` (`id`,`flag`) VALUES
(1,'[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"d\"]');
(2,'[\"b\", \"c\", \"d\", \"f\"]');
(3,'[\"a\", \"b\", \"1\", \"2\"]');
(4,'[\"a\", \"c\", \"1\", \"3\"]');
(5,'[\"a\", \"9\", \"10\", \"2\"]');
COMMIT;
```

When I use JSON_ When a query is made by `JSON_CONTAINS(mangas.flag, '[\"a\",\"b\"]', '$')`, it can find all the data containing a and b

But I want to query and exclude all data with a or b. what should I do?

Maybe I didn't express my needs clearly

Here is a normal not in query

`select * from tabel1 where a not in('a','b','c')`

How to implement this not in query in JSON field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_REMOVE() to exclude the data from the JSON. Have a look at this example,

https://database.guide/json_remove-remove-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: I've looked at this article, which explains how to delete data in JSON, which is not the effect I want

My requirement is to achieve a query similar to `where abc not in (1,2,3)`